# Display Microsoft Office Updates and their installation date

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

Anyone know how I can display Microsoft Office updates with their installation date, publishing date by microsoft and other details?

I have found WinUpdatesList, but it shows only Windows updates.
I have windows 2003 server and WinUpdateList does not show office updates.

Comment: Why do you need "a software" to do this? Maybe there's a built-in command line solution for this too…

Comment: Windows Update displays this information.  Microsoft has a single website ( I don't have it handy ) which has the ability to list every update for every product they have released to date.

Comment: @slhck - Isn't this Off-Topic since it is explicitly soliciting a product recommendation?  OP - Instead, I would suggest that you edit your question to be "How can I display all Microsoft Office updates?  Seeing that with details would be a bonus.".  That would get you better answers all around, in my opinion.  Otherwise, you are segmenting your scope to be limited to 3rd party stuff (which as it stands looks off-topic per the [help](http://superuser.com/help) pages).

Comment: @nerdwaller Don't take the "product recommendation" thing so literally. It was meant for *what's the best foo app* or *what XYZ converters are there?*, not for questions that obviously ask for a very specific problem to be solved, even if they mention the word "software". We just don't want an endless set of answers or one-line posts.

Comment: Nirsoft WinUpdatesList v1.31 **does** show the installed Office updates.

Comment: @slhck - Thanks, never really knew where the line was on that one.  I guess since the OS will be around a while - it can help in the future too - which seems to be the goal of that limitation.  **OP** - It may be helpful to know which version of Windows you are using.  The update protocols were a bit different between XP, Vista, & 7/8 which may change the software that does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right app for windows 2003 server and office 2010 is myuninstaller

and you can get the portable [here](http://www.pendriveapps.com/myuninstaller/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying 'with installation date' I am assuming that you want to have the list of updates installed on your machine. You're not saying which Windows version.

The Win 7 Configuration screen/Programs has a link for Installed updates at the top left.

Earlier Win versions have a checkbox 'Include installed updates'.

This list will not have publication date etc. Under Win 7 I notice that you can display additional columns (right-click on a column header). On my Dutch version the one named *Helpkoppeling* (should be something like *Help link* in English) shows URLs that lead you to the detail knowledge base pages.